# Statistics, Poisson Distribution

Tags: statistics

Let's say that I owe two cars that I want to rent out. 
The demand for a car is random and have a mean of 1.5 requests per day.

What's the probability that both cars are hired out on any particular day?

Given the Poisson Distribution I would like to believe that it is $(3^2
 \cdot e^{-3})/2!$
I only have a number that's supposed to be final answer and that number is not the same as I get if I use the above written.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You appeared to use 3 in place of $\lambda$ in your formulas. Why?

Comment: You say the mean is $1.5$ and yet you use $\lambda = 3$. Why is that?

Comment: With 1.5, I get .251

Comment: The demand for a car (one car) is random with a mean of 1.5 a day. I have 2 cars so shouldn't the mean requests per day then be 3? That's part of my question also. According to my lecture notes it should be 0.442...

Comment: $\lambda = 3$ would be the demand for two days. If you had 10 cars would that raise the demand to 15 per day?

Comment: No of course not @BruceET. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your professor has in mind that both cars will be hired out
if the demand is for two or more cars.

If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1.5),\,$ then

$$P(X \ge 2) = 1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1) = 1 -e^{-1.5}(1 + 1.5) = 0.4421746.$$

Using R statistical software (where `ppois` is the Poisson CDF) one gets:

```
1 - ppois(1, 1.5)
## 0.4421746
```